# Convert BST to DLL in pre-order (base)

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I have a BST, and I have to make it into a two-way linked list on pre-order base. The function should change the pointers of each node in the tree so that the left pointer points to the previous member in the list, and the right pointer points to the next one. (The previous(left) of the root is NULL; likewise next of the last node(right) is NULL.)
I should return the head of the created DLL to print the list.

Obstacles: You can not use auxiliary functions and you have to change the pointers of the tree itself and not create a new list.
The implementation is in C.

```
      4                               
    /   \       
   2      6    ---------> output of DLL: 4<->2<->1<->3<->6<->5<->7.         
 /  \     / \                         
1    3   5   7
```

Here is my code; I hope someone would help me here.

```
Node* converToPreOrder(Node* root)
{
    if (root == NULL) return root;

    static Node* head = NULL; 
    static Node* prev = NULL; 
    Node* temp = root;

    if (prev == NULL) 
        head = root;

    if (root->right != NULL && root->left != NULL)
        prev = root;

    else
    {
        prev->right = root;
        temp->left = prev;
    }

    converToPreOrder(root->left);
    converToPreOrder(root->right);

    return head;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  Have you run your code?  What answer did you get?  How did you demonstrate that you had a correctly structured BST?  How do you demonstrate that you have a coherent DLL?  These are aspects of an MCVE ([MCVE]).  — Under what circumstances do you think the assignment in `if (prev == NULL) 
    head = root;` will not be executed?  Why didn't you simply initialize `head`, then?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that seems to work.  The conversion function is quite simple in concept, but requires some care in handling the details.

For this problem, it seems to me that when you are processing any given node, you need to get three elements:

- the current node (root)
- the list for the left-child (which is generated recursively)
- the list for the right-child (which is also generated recursively)

And the resulting list needs to be:

- current node, followed by
- the list for the left-child, followed by
- the list for the right-child.

Given the tree from the question:

```
      4                               
    /   \       
   2      6    ---------> output of DLL: 4<->2<->1<->3<->6<->5<->7.         
 /  \     / \                         
1    3   5   7
```

The final result is:

- node 4, followed by the list from node 2, followed by the list from node 6.

Of course, the list from node 2 is:

- node 2, followed by the list from node 1, followed by the list from node 3.
- And the lists from node 1 and node 3 are trivial, so the result is:

  - node 2, node 1, node 3

And similarly the list from node 6 is:

- node 6, followed by the list from node 5, followed by the list from node 7.

  - And the lists from node 5 and node 7 are trivial, so the result is:
- node 6, node 5, node 7

And hence the final result is:

- node 4, node 2, node 1, node 3, node 6, node 5, node 7

The lists are doubly-linked and null-terminated.  That means that on return to the invocation processing node 4, the left list has the organization:

```
       +--------+     +--------+     +--------+
0 <----|        |<----|        |<----|        |
       | Node 2 |     | Node 1 |     | Node 3 |
       |        |---->|        |---->|        |----> 0
       +--------+     +--------+     +--------+
```

The trivial cases return a list with null next and previous pointers.  The right list has a similar organization for Nodes 6, 5, 7 in sequence.  Assembling the final result requires setting the left pointer of Node 4 to null, setting the right pointer of Node 4 to the head of the left list, setting the left pointer of the head of the left list to Node 4, finding the end of the list starting from Node 4's right pointer, and then adding the right list after that and setting the left pointer of head of the right list to the right pointer of the node pointing at the right list.

Either the left list or the right list or both can be empty; these require a modicum of care.

This is the resulting code, complete with a trio of test cases.  The pointer to pointer to node technique for traversing lists is rather powerful and worth learning.  You can find other SO questions for the technique, such as:

- [What is the double-pointer technique for simplifying the traversal of linked lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182733/what-is-the-double-pointer-technique-for-simplifying-the-traversal-of-linked-lis/3182787#3182787)
- [An interesting linked list idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332441/an-interesting-c-linked-list-idiom)

```
/* SO 4784-9166 */
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node
{
    int   number;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
};

static Node *convertToPreOrder(Node *root)
{
    if (root == 0)
        return 0;
    Node *l_list = convertToPreOrder(root->left);
    Node *r_list = convertToPreOrder(root->right);
    root->left = 0;
    /* Add left list */
    root->right = l_list;
    if (l_list != 0)
        l_list->left = root;
    /* Find the end */
    Node **pos = &root;
    while ((*pos)->right != 0)
        pos = &(*pos)->right;
    /* Add right list */
    (*pos)->right = r_list;
    if (r_list != 0)
        r_list->left = *pos;
    return root;
}

static void print_node(Node *node)
{
    if (node != 0)
        printf("Node = 0x%.12" PRIXPTR " - Number = %d - "
               "Left = 0x%.12" PRIXPTR " - Right = 0x%.12" PRIXPTR "\n",
               (uintptr_t)node, node->number, (uintptr_t)node->left, (uintptr_t)node->right);
}

static void print_BST_preorder(Node *root)
{
    if (root == 0)
        return;
    print_node(root);
    print_BST_preorder(root->left);
    print_BST_preorder(root->right);
}

static void print_list(Node *list)
{
    while (list != 0)
    {
        print_node(list);
        list = list->right;
    }
}

static Node *add_bst_node(Node *root, Node *node)
{
    if (root == 0)
        return node;
    if (node->number >= root->number)
        root->right = add_bst_node(root->right, node);
    else
        root->left = add_bst_node(root->left, node);
    return root;
}

static void test_bst_to_list(size_t n_nodes, Node nodes[])
{
    Node *root = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_nodes; i++)
        root = add_bst_node(root, &nodes[i]);
    printf("Print BST in pre-order:\n");
    print_BST_preorder(root);
    printf("Convert to list\n");
    Node *list = convertToPreOrder(root);
    printf("Print list:\n");
    print_list(list);
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    Node array1[] =
    {
        { 4, 0, 0 },
        { 2, 0, 0 },
        { 1, 0, 0 },
        { 3, 0, 0 },
        { 6, 0, 0 },
        { 5, 0, 0 },
        { 7, 0, 0 },
    };
    enum { ARRAY1_SIZE = sizeof(array1) / sizeof(array1[0]) };
    test_bst_to_list(ARRAY1_SIZE, array1);

    Node array2[] =
    {
        { 19, 0, 0 },
        { 21, 0, 0 },
        { 20, 0, 0 },
        { 18, 0, 0 },
        { 22, 0, 0 },
        { 24, 0, 0 },
        { 17, 0, 0 },
        { 16, 0, 0 },
        { 23, 0, 0 },
        { 27, 0, 0 },
        { 26, 0, 0 },
        { 25, 0, 0 },
    };
    enum { ARRAY2_SIZE = sizeof(array2) / sizeof(array2[0]) };
    test_bst_to_list(ARRAY2_SIZE, array2);

    Node array3[] =
    {
        { 16, 0, 0 },
        { 11, 0, 0 },
        { 21, 0, 0 },
        { 10, 0, 0 },
        { 22, 0, 0 },
        { 22, 0, 0 },
        { 21, 0, 0 },
        { 27, 0, 0 },
        { 27, 0, 0 },
        { 20, 0, 0 },
        { 22, 0, 0 },
        { 17, 0, 0 },
        { 12, 0, 0 },
    };
    enum { ARRAY3_SIZE = sizeof(array3) / sizeof(array3[0]) };
    test_bst_to_list(ARRAY3_SIZE, array3);

    return 0;
}
```

The `print_node()` function is tuned to running on a Mac (in 64-bit), where memory addresses typically have leading zeroes in the first 4 nybbles, so 12 hex digits is sufficient to print them.

Sample output:

```
Print BST in pre-order:
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B180 - Number = 4 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B198 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B1E0
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B198 - Number = 2 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B1B0 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B1C8
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B1B0 - Number = 1 - Left = 0x000000000000 - Right = 0x000000000000
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B1C8 - Number = 3 - Left = 0x000000000000 - Right = 0x000000000000
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B1E0 - Number = 6 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B1F8 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B210
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B1F8 - Number = 5 - Left = 0x000000000000 - Right = 0x000000000000
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B210 - Number = 7 - Left = 0x000000000000 - Right = 0x000000000000
Convert to list
Print list:
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B180 - Number = 4 - Left = 0x000000000000 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B198
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B198 - Number = 2 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B180 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B1B0
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B1B0 - Number = 1 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B198 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B1C8
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B1C8 - Number = 3 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B1B0 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B1E0
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B1E0 - Number = 6 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B1C8 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B1F8
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B1F8 - Number = 5 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B1E0 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B210
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B210 - Number = 7 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B1F8 - Right = 0x000000000000

Print BST in pre-order:
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B230 - Number = 19 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B278 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B248
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B278 - Number = 18 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B2C0 - Right = 0x000000000000
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B2C0 - Number = 17 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B2D8 - Right = 0x000000000000
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B2D8 - Number = 16 - Left = 0x000000000000 - Right = 0x000000000000
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B248 - Number = 21 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B260 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B290
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B260 - Number = 20 - Left = 0x000000000000 - Right = 0x000000000000
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B290 - Number = 22 - Left = 0x000000000000 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B2A8
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B2A8 - Number = 24 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B2F0 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B308
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B2F0 - Number = 23 - Left = 0x000000000000 - Right = 0x000000000000
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B308 - Number = 27 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B320 - Right = 0x000000000000
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B320 - Number = 26 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B338 - Right = 0x000000000000
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B338 - Number = 25 - Left = 0x000000000000 - Right = 0x000000000000
Convert to list
Print list:
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B230 - Number = 19 - Left = 0x000000000000 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B278
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B278 - Number = 18 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B230 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B2C0
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B2C0 - Number = 17 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B278 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B2D8
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B2D8 - Number = 16 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B2C0 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B248
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B248 - Number = 21 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B2D8 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B260
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B260 - Number = 20 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B248 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B290
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B290 - Number = 22 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B260 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B2A8
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B2A8 - Number = 24 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B290 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B2F0
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B2F0 - Number = 23 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B2A8 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B308
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B308 - Number = 27 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B2F0 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B320
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B320 - Number = 26 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B308 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B338
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B338 - Number = 25 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B320 - Right = 0x000000000000

Print BST in pre-order:
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B350 - Number = 16 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B368 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B380
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B368 - Number = 11 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B398 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B470
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B398 - Number = 10 - Left = 0x000000000000 - Right = 0x000000000000
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B470 - Number = 12 - Left = 0x000000000000 - Right = 0x000000000000
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B380 - Number = 21 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B428 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B3B0
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B428 - Number = 20 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B458 - Right = 0x000000000000
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B458 - Number = 17 - Left = 0x000000000000 - Right = 0x000000000000
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B3B0 - Number = 22 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B3E0 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B3C8
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B3E0 - Number = 21 - Left = 0x000000000000 - Right = 0x000000000000
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B3C8 - Number = 22 - Left = 0x000000000000 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B3F8
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B3F8 - Number = 27 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B440 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B410
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B440 - Number = 22 - Left = 0x000000000000 - Right = 0x000000000000
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B410 - Number = 27 - Left = 0x000000000000 - Right = 0x000000000000
Convert to list
Print list:
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B350 - Number = 16 - Left = 0x000000000000 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B368
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B368 - Number = 11 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B350 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B398
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B398 - Number = 10 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B368 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B470
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B470 - Number = 12 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B398 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B380
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B380 - Number = 21 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B470 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B428
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B428 - Number = 20 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B380 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B458
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B458 - Number = 17 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B428 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B3B0
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B3B0 - Number = 22 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B458 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B3E0
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B3E0 - Number = 21 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B3B0 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B3C8
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B3C8 - Number = 22 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B3E0 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B3F8
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B3F8 - Number = 27 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B3C8 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B440
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B440 - Number = 22 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B3F8 - Right = 0x7FFEE6F5B410
Node = 0x7FFEE6F5B410 - Number = 27 - Left = 0x7FFEE6F5B440 - Right = 0x000000000000
```

The first test case corresponds to the sample tree from the question.  Given the construction of the tree, the nodes are presented in the same order in both the BST print and the list print.  However, the pointers are quite different.  That test case is a little too simple for comfort.  It doesn't test the cases where a given node in the BST has either an empty left tree or an empty right tree (but not both — that would be a leaf node).