# Is free() missing in this "good taste" and "bad taste"code?

Tags: c, linked-list

In an interview about Linus Torvalds, he shared about the importance of having "good taste". He explained good taste with the following code.

Code with "bad taste"

```
remove_list_entry(entry)
{
    prev = NULL;
    walk = head;

    // Walk the list

    while (walk != entry) {
        prev = walk;
        walk = walk->next;
    }

    // Remove the entry by updating the head
    // or the previous entry

    if (!entry)
        head = entry->next;
    else
        prev-next = entry->next;
}
```

Code with "good taste"

```
remove_list_entry(entry)
{
    // The "indirect" pointer points to the
    // *address* of the thing we'll update

    indirect = &head;

    // Walk the list, looking for the thing that
    // points to the thing we want to remove

    while ((*indirect) != entry)
        indirect = &(*indirect)->next;

    // .. and just remove it
    *indirect = entry->next;
}
```

Both examples haven't use `free()` to release the memory of the node to be deleted. Can someone tell me why the code is written in this way? Or am I having the wrong concept regarding to C or linked list?

Comment: Can you provide a link/reference to the interview?

Comment: It depends on the general design of the list. Removing a node from a list does not mean that the node may not be used any longer.

Comment: Style aside, isn't the top example broken?

Comment: You can find one question about the pointer-to-pointer linked list processing technique at [What is the pointer to pointer technique for the simpler traversal of linked lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182733/what-is-the-pointer-to-pointer-technique-for-the-simpler-traversal-of-linked-lis/) which is closed as a duplicate of [An interesting C linked list idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332441/an-interesting-c-linked-list-idiom).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Both are only pseudo code. I wouldn't expect any of them to be complete. In a real "good taste" example `head` would probably not be a global variable. And some `NULL` checks would also be included.

Answer (score 3):

It is important also to note the semantics of this function.  It is intended to *remove* a node from a list, not to *delete* the node as you suggest in your question.  At least that is implied by the function name.  I would be surprised if it deleted the node without advertising that semantic.

Moreover we have no way of knowing in isolation how the object was allocated, so the function cannot reasonably assume it is a heap object and `free()` it - that would cause a run-time error if the object were static.

The caller may be removing the object from the list and continuing to use it, it is the responsibility of this function to maintain the *list* not the objects in the list which have independent existence.  It is the responsibility of the owner of `entry` to manage its memory.

Comment: _and free() it - that would cause a run-time error if the object were static_: freeing something that hasn't been allocated by `malloc` and friends does not necessarily trigger a runtime error, it's just UB.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It would be a semantic error not  trapped at build time.  In that sense an error occurring at run time.  That is all I meant, not necessarily an error that is explicitly trapped by the runtime environment. I hope that is clear?

Comment: It is (and always was) clear to me, but it might not be clear to the OP.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks, clarity is served by your comment.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, good taste is being exemplified by minimalism; the second example is less ornate and more to the point than the first.   The bad taste code has a few errors in it, but the point is that the extra variable and if statement are superfluous.

Taste is a subjective quality, and there are many reasons to favour either approach.  To me, taste has always been about readability.  Readability doesn't clear favour either approach -- TLDR vs Too Complex; Didn't Bother (TC;DB).

Compiler technology has a fashion mavens influence on taste.  Long ago, when peep hole optimisation was the thing, the second version was preferred; it generated significantly less code.   In the not-so-old days compilers dallied with data flow analysis, and liked the first version because it the pointer chasing was clearly not a hidden alias (unlike the second).   Modern compilers, so hip with gobs of memory and cpu permit better alias checking, so have gone back to the first.  Even still, in your example, it is 3 instructions different.