# Linked list returning root node in singly-linked list C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

I am writing a program to delete the nodes greater than x. I want to return the root node of the linked list after deleting.  I save the new root node in variable "root". But unfortunately, when I get root in the main function, the value seems to be 0. Can anyone please help me identify the issue?**

```
// structure of a node
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

// function to get a new node
Node* getNode(int data)
{
  
    Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

// function to delete all the nodes from the list
// that are greater than the specified value x
Node *deleteGreaterNodes(Node* head_ref, int x)
{
    Node *temp = head_ref, *prev;
    static Node *root;

    // If head node itself holds the value greater than 'x'
    if (temp != NULL && temp->data > x) {
        head_ref = temp->next; // Changed head
        free(temp); // free old head
        temp = head_ref; // Change temp
    }
    root = temp;
    // Delete occurrences other than head
    while (temp != NULL) {

        // Search for the node to be deleted,
        // keep track of the previous node as we
        // need to change 'prev->next'
        while (temp != NULL && temp->data <= x) {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        // If required value node was not present
        // in linked list
        if (temp == NULL)
            return 0;

        // Unlink the node from linked list
        prev->next = temp->next;

        free (temp); // Free memory

        // Update Temp for next iteration of
        // outer loop
        temp = prev->next;
    }
    return head_ref;
}

// function to a print a linked list
void printList(Node* head)
{
    while (head) {
       
        printf("%d ",head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
}

// Driver program to test above
int main()
{
    static Node *root;
    // Create list: 7->3->4->8->5->1
    Node* head = getNode(7);
    head->next = getNode(3);
    head->next->next = getNode(4);
    head->next->next->next = getNode(8);
    head->next->next->next->next = getNode(5);
    head->next->next->next->next->next = getNode(1);

    int x = 3;

   
     printf("Original List: "); 
    printList(head);

   root = deleteGreaterNodes(head, x);
     
     printf("\nModified List: "); 
    printList(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't use `cout << "Original List: ";` in a C program.  Don't use a C++ compiler to compile a C program.  Since the rest of the code does seem to be C rather than C++, you can simply edit that line out (there's an equivalent `printf()` after it).  But please be careful.

Comment: The last node in your ist has the value 1, which isn'r greater than three. In the inermost loop, you advance past all nodes you want to keep and if you reach the end, you `return 0`.  So the code that returns 0 is right there, in your code.

Comment: I take it back — you are using another feature of C++ than just a stray `cout`.  You define `struct Node`; in C++ that also defines a type `Node`, but it does not in C.  You'd need `typedef struct Node Node;` or equivalent before defining the structure type.  You shouldn't use `static Node *root;` in either place where it is used.  In `main()`, it should be a simple local (automatic) variable.  In `deleteGreaterNodes()`, it should be removed altogether.

Comment: Thanks  @M Oehm . That was it ! I was returning 0 at the end . Now I changed it to return my head node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way of implementing `deleteGreaterNodes` is to use an extra level of indirection to access the `Node *` links.

```
// function to delete all the nodes from the list
// that are greater than the specified value x
Node *deleteGreaterNodes(Node* head_ref, int x)
{
    Node **link = &head_ref; // Point to the pointer to the first node.
    Node *cur;

    while ((cur = *link) != NULL) {
        if (cur->data > x) {
            // The current node needs to be deleted from the list.
            // Change the link pointing to the current node to point to the next node.
            *link = cur->next;
            // Delete the current node.
            free(cur);
        } else {
            // The current node is to be kept on the list.
            // Get a pointer to the link to the next node.
            link = &cur->next;
        }
    }
    return head_ref;
}
```

Comment: The 'double-pointer' technique is interesting — see also [An interesting C linked list idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332441/an-interesting-c-linked-list-idiom) and [What is the pointer-to-pointer technique for simplifying the traversal of linked lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182733/what-is-the-double-pointer-technique-for-simplifying-the-traversal-of-linked-lis/)

Answer (score 2):

For starters do not mix in one translation unit two languages C and C++.

Either write a C or C++ program.

For example this declaration in C

```
// structure of a node
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;
};
```

is incorrect, You have to write

```
// structure of a node
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};
```

There is no great sense to declare the static variable `root`

```
static Node *root;
```

and then one more variable `head`.

```
// Create list: 7->3->4->8->5->1
Node* head = getNode(7);
```

Your function `deleteGreaterNodes` is too complicated and as any complicated function it contains a bug in this code snippet

```
    // If required value node was not present
    // in linked list
    if (temp == NULL)
        return 0;
```

because it returns a null pointer instead of returning the pointer `head_ref`.

Here is your updated program that was adjusted according to the C language that contains a modified function `deleteGreaterNodes`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// structure of a node
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

// function to get a new node
struct Node* getNode(int data)
{
  
    struct Node* newNode = ( struct Node * )malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

// function to delete all the nodes from the list
// that are greater than the specified value x

struct Node *deleteGreaterNodes( struct Node* head_ref, int x )
{
    while ( head_ref && x < head_ref->data )
    {
        struct Node *tmp = head_ref;
        head_ref = head_ref->next;
        free( tmp );
    }
    
    if ( head_ref )
    {
        for ( struct Node *current = head_ref; current->next != NULL; )
        {
            if ( x < current->next->data )
            {
                struct Node *tmp = current->next;
                current->next = current->next->next;
                free( tmp );
            }
            else
            {
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return head_ref;
}

// function to a print a linked list
void printList(struct Node* head)
{
    while (head) {
       
        printf("%d ",head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
}

// Driver program to test above
int main()
{
    struct Node* head = getNode(7);
    head->next = getNode(3);
    head->next->next = getNode(4);
    head->next->next->next = getNode(8);
    head->next->next->next->next = getNode(5);
    head->next->next->next->next->next = getNode(1);

    int x = 3;

    printf( "Original List: " );
    // printf("Original List: "); 
    printList(head);

   head = deleteGreaterNodes(head, x);

    
     printf("\nModified List: "); 
    printList( head );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Original List: 7 3 4 8 5 1 
Modified List: 3 1
```

Comment: Thanks for saving me the bother of writing the equivalent answer.  Except that I added `typedef struct Node Node;` before the structure was defined (and therefore didn't need to add `struct` in other places too), you've got the same diagnosis as I came up with.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Adding the typedef was more efficient to update the program.:)

Comment: How can you print only the head node only and then delete it?

Comment: @wajaap This is not related to the original question. If you have  a problem you can ask your own question at SO.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow just did, can you check [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70986400/how-can-i-keep-a-variable-from-the-first-element-in-the-list) please?